How to install Storybook properly in Expo project?
I have created a demo project on react-native following the instruction on their official site. I chose to use Expo platform and the project is typescript based. I tried to add a storybook also following the instructions on their official site. Installing it with the line bellow
npx sb init --type react

allowed me to run successfully a storybook with default installation. Durring installation I had to choose between Webpack 5 or Vite and I selected Webpack. The installation completed with no errors. But that storybook is not capble of resolving React Native components. Then I execute another line according to the instructions:
yarn add react-dom react-native-web babel-plugin-react-native-web @storybook/addon-react-native-web @react-native/babel-preset --dev


Then I modified .storybook/main.ts to include a plugin that would allow me to import React Native components in my storybook as explained in the official site. After that I tried to run the storybook, but the terminal gave me the following error:
> yarn storybook
yarn run v1.22.19
warning ../package.json: No license field
$ storybook dev -p 6006
@storybook/core v8.3.6

info => Starting manager..
info => Starting preview..
info => Using implicit CSS loaders
Using @react-native/babel-preset
info => Using default Webpack5 setup
<i> [webpack-dev-middleware] wait until bundle finished
ERROR in main
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'babel-loader' in '/home/zemia/Coding/prime.code/pawmatix'

preview compiled with 1 error
=> Failed to build the preview
99% end closing watch compilationWARN Force closed preview build
SB_BUILDER-WEBPACK5_0003 (WebpackCompilationError): There were problems when compiling your code with Webpack.
Run Storybook with --debug-webpack for more information.
    at starter (./node_modules/@storybook/builder-webpack5/dist/index.js:1:8004)
    at starter.next (<anonymous>)
    at Module.start (./node_modules/@storybook/builder-webpack5/dist/index.js:1:9972)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async storybookDevServer (./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/core-server/index.cjs:47328:11)
    at async buildOrThrow (./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/core-server/index.cjs:46581:12)
    at async buildDevStandalone (./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/core-server/index.cjs:48518:78)
    at async withTelemetry (./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/core-server/index.cjs:47080:12)
    at async dev (./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/cli/bin/index.cjs:2877:3)
    at async r.<anonymous> (./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/cli/bin/index.cjs:2929:74)

WARN Broken build, fix the error above.
WARN You may need to refresh the browser.

I installed babel-loader, because I neighter found that package mentioned anywhere in my package.json, nor it existed under node_modules. Thats the command I applied for installing babel-loader as sugested in the official repository.
npm install -D babel-loader @babel/core @babel/preset-env webpack

Storybook initialization is still broken but that time with another error:
$ npm run storybook

> pawmatix@1.0.0 storybook
> storybook dev -p 6006

@storybook/core v8.3.6


attention => Storybook now collects completely anonymous telemetry regarding usage.
This information is used to shape Storybook's roadmap and prioritize features.
You can learn more, including how to opt-out if you'd not like to participate in this anonymous program, by visiting the following URL:
https://storybook.js.org/telemetry

info => Starting manager..
info => Starting preview..
info => Using implicit CSS loaders
Using @react-native/babel-preset
info => Using default Webpack5 setup
<i> [webpack-dev-middleware] wait until bundle finished
ERROR in ./node_modules/@storybook/instrumenter/dist/index.js 1:2542-2556
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tty' in '/home/zemia/Coding/prime.code/pawmatix/node_modules/@storybook/instrumenter/dist'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "tty": require.resolve("tty-browserify") }'
    - install 'tty-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "tty": false }
 @ ./node_modules/@storybook/test/dist/index.js 20:13534-13568 179:26783-26817
 @ ./stories/Page.stories.ts 1:306-332
 @ ./stories/ lazy ^\.\/.*$ namespace object ./Page.stories.ts ./Page.stories
 @ ./storybook-stories.js 1:551-585 1:901-935
 @ ./storybook-config-entry.js 1:174-207 1:929-1061

ERROR in ./node_modules/@storybook/test/dist/index.js 11:23752-23765
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'os' in '/home/zemia/Coding/prime.code/pawmatix/node_modules/@storybook/test/dist'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "os": require.resolve("os-browserify/browser") }'
    - install 'os-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "os": false }
 @ ./stories/Page.stories.ts 1:306-332
 @ ./stories/ lazy ^\.\/.*$ namespace object ./Page.stories.ts ./Page.stories
 @ ./storybook-stories.js 1:551-585 1:901-935
 @ ./storybook-config-entry.js 1:174-207 1:929-1061

ERROR in ./node_modules/@storybook/test/dist/index.js 11:23770-23784
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tty' in '/home/zemia/Coding/prime.code/pawmatix/node_modules/@storybook/test/dist'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "tty": require.resolve("tty-browserify") }'
    - install 'tty-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "tty": false }
 @ ./stories/Page.stories.ts 1:306-332
 @ ./stories/ lazy ^\.\/.*$ namespace object ./Page.stories.ts ./Page.stories
 @ ./storybook-stories.js 1:551-585 1:901-935
 @ ./storybook-config-entry.js 1:174-207 1:929-1061

ERROR in ./stories/Configure.mdx 18:32
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (18:32)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| import AddonLibrary from "./assets/addon-library.png";
| 
> export const RightArrow = () => <svg 
|     viewBox="0 0 14 14" 
|     width="8px" 
 @ ./stories/ lazy ^\.\/.*$ namespace object ./Configure.mdx
 @ ./storybook-stories.js 1:551-585 1:901-935
 @ ./storybook-config-entry.js 1:174-207 1:929-1061

ERROR in ./stories/assets/avif-test-image.avif 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
 @ ./stories/ lazy ^\.\/.*$ namespace object ./assets/avif-test-image.avif
 @ ./storybook-stories.js 1:551-585 1:901-935
 @ ./storybook-config-entry.js 1:174-207 1:929-1061

preview compiled with 5 errors
=> Failed to build the preview
99% end closing watch compilationWARN Force closed preview build
SB_BUILDER-WEBPACK5_0003 (WebpackCompilationError): There were problems when compiling your code with Webpack.
Run Storybook with --debug-webpack for more information.
    at starter (./node_modules/@storybook/builder-webpack5/dist/index.js:1:8004)
    at starter.next (<anonymous>)
    at Module.start (./node_modules/@storybook/builder-webpack5/dist/index.js:1:9972)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

WARN Broken build, fix the error above.
WARN You may need to refresh the browser.


My package.json dependencies before the babel-loader's installation:
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^14.0.2",
    "@react-native/babel-preset": "^0.76.1",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.2",
    "@storybook/addon-react-native-web": "^0.0.26",
    "babel-plugin-react-native-web": "^0.19.13",
    "expo": "~51.0.28",
    "expo-constants": "~16.0.2",
    "expo-dev-client": "~4.0.28",
    "expo-font": "~12.0.9",
    "expo-linking": "~6.3.1",
    "expo-router": "~3.5.23",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.27.5",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.12.1",
    "expo-system-ui": "~3.0.7",
    "expo-web-browser": "~13.0.3",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.74.5",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.16.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.10.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.10.5",
    "react-native-screens": "3.31.1",
    "react-native-web": "^0.19.13",
    "redux": "^5.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@chromatic-com/storybook": "^1.9.0",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^8.3.6",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions": "^8.3.6",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^8.3.6",
    "@storybook/addon-onboarding": "^8.3.6",
    "@storybook/addon-webpack5-compiler-swc": "^1.0.5",
    "@storybook/blocks": "^8.3.6",
    "@storybook/react": "^8.3.6",
    "@storybook/react-webpack5": "^8.3.6",
    "@storybook/test": "^8.3.6",
    "@tsconfig/react-native": "^3.0.5",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.14",
    "@types/react": "~18.2.45",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.3.0",
    "jest": "^29.2.1",
    "jest-expo": "~51.0.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "storybook": "^8.3.6",
    "typescript": "~5.3.3"
  },

Node version: v20.3.1

I was trying to install storybook in Expo project, but the instructions I was following are for plain ReactNative project.
Option 1
Eventually I ended up with pre-configured template of Expo + Storybook from the official storybook repository The following one-line command can install it for you.
npx create-expo-app --template expo-template-storybook AwesomeStorybook

Option 2
In my oppinion a better approach is to use a monorepo. To do so I created a root folder having packages folder and package.json. The file has "workspaces": ["packages/*"] property.
{
  "private": true,
  "name": "monorepo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=23.1.0"
  },
  "workspaces": [
    "packages/*"
  ]
}

In packages folder I created two template Expo projects with the commands
npx create-expo-app@latest mobile
npx create-expo-app@latest design

so that they created two apps under folder mobile and design. In design I put the components and confiture the storybook, in mobile is the app that I'm developing.
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
└── packages
    ├── design
    └── mobile

In the package.json of design I set the main property to index.tsx where I export all components. Then I import them in mobile app like if it is a node library.
To set up the design folder I followed these instructions for configuring Storybook in an existing project. The idea for a Storybook in a monorepo I took from here. I followed the steps there except for Storybook installation and configuration, which I took from the Storybooks' official repo link above.
